# Need the drivers for a laptop model ASUS G752VL (Republic of Gamers) running Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, sound, brightness

I've changed the hard drive in my computer from a Windows-loaded one to another one loaded with Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. However, after I have installed Ubuntu, I've noticed

- The trackpad doesn't work for scrolling.
- The brightness can't be adjusted with the brightness buttons.
- Every time on bootup the brightness is on max.
- The audio jacks doesn't output or input sound to/from a headphone or a microphone, respectively.

After some research I found out missing ASUS drivers are the issue, and I would have to get them from wily-backport somehow from ASUS via the terminal. However, the ASUS tech forums appear outdated and so I would like to know how to install these drivers to Linux in order to avoid these inconveniences.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can search additional drivers in the dash and it will give you the option to search for any additional drivers that the system might find missing.

Hope this helps!

leave me alone Tim

Comment: Thank you for this one. Though I was geared more towards using the terminal and using `backport`.